# Passwordless authentication using expiring hardware keys

Tags: authentication, windows, hardware-token, fido2

I am looking for a solution to implement passwordless authentication using expirable hardware keys. It is for devices around the world with Windows OS, and sometimes service technicians have to do something there, so I want an admin account to be available only for technicians with such keys. To avoid problems with lost/stolen keys, they must expire and be renewed e.g. once a month.

1. One device may accept multiple keys, but only the ones it knows. It is possible to preconfigure something before a device is shipped to a customer.
2. A key has to have a battery and an embedded clock to check if it is expired. Such feature exists on some license keys as far as I know.
3. A login/password authorization has to be disabled for admin user to accept only hardware keys.

I've read about FIDO2 but I am not sure if it is possible to have the three features listed above with some FIDO2 device.

Comment: What connectivity is there at point-of-use?  Expiring things is hard without a reliable and trustworthy clock source (can be GPS, secure NTP, etc).  Trusting a clock in the key is a bad idea.

Comment: A device will have a modem as an option to collect some predictive maintenance data. But it probably will not work in some countries. So, I consider this device as offline one. Why trusting a clock in a kay is a bad idea? License dongles usually have it and rely on it.

Comment: Because the point of a lock is to reject fake keys.  Nothing about the key can be trusted, it has to be challenged.  License dongles work through challenge-response.